# illegal property webservice

Tags: android, web-service, ksoap2

Estou tendo um problema na hora de consumir meu webservice.

Tenho o seguinte método (Este método irá retornar todos os usuários cadastrados no webservice que estão no banco) Usuário possui (id,nome):

```
public ArrayList<Usuario> buscarTodosUsuario(){ 

    ArrayList<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

    SoapObject buscarUsuario = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, BUSCARTODOS);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarUsuario);
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        http.call("urn= "  + BUSCARTODOS, envelope);

        Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();

        for (SoapObject soapObject : resposta) {
            Usuario user = new Usuario();
            user.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("id").toString()));
            user.setNome(soapObject.getProperty("nome").toString());
            lista.add(user);                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return lista;
}
```

A chamada do método é:

```
ArrayList<Usuario> lista = dao.buscarTodosUsuario();
Log.d("ExemploWS", lista + "");
```

O erro é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A classe Usuario é:

```
package com.example.testawebservice;

public class Usuario{
    private int id;
    private String nomeusuario;

    public Usuario(){
    }

    public Usuario(int id, String nomeusuario) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nomeusuario = nomeusuario;
    }

    public int getIdUsuario() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nomeusuario;
    }

    public void setNome(String nomeusuario) {
        this.nomeusuario = nomeusuario;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuario [id=" + id + ", nomeusuario="
                + nomeusuario + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está com um erro na linha `user.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("id").toString()));`. Poderia [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar o código da classe `Usuario`?

Comment: Editei e coloquei a classe usuário! Tenho a percepção que realmente é algo com esse atributo em especifico, pois com o "Nomeusuario" não teve problema

Comment: Se você trocar a linha em questão e colocar: `System.out.println(soapObject.getProperty(0));` no lugar dela, o que é impresso no console?

Comment: Aparece o número 6. Que é a ID do meu primeiro usuário cadastrado no banco! E começa aparecer o mesmo erro, só que agora para o outro atributo, nomeusuario.

Comment: Eu não sei como você define esses `property`s, mas algo me diz que você não está conseguindo dar um "nome" para eles, uma solução é você usar 0 para o `id` e 1 para o `nomeUsuario`, caso não queira fazer assim precisa ver onde você faz essa associação do nome do `property` com o atributo do seu POJO Usuario. PS: Eu não faço ideia de como se usa esse ksoap, portanto não tem como eu falar onde isso é feito, se você souber adiciona na sua resposta essa classe/arquivo de configuração ou seja lá onde configura esses caras.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda Math... Acabei descobrindo... Na verdade estava focada no método e na classe usuário, mas o problema é que no webservice estava como "idUsuario" e "nomeUsuario", quando a KSOAP tenta pegar a propriedade "idusuario" ou "nomeusuario" ele não encontrava, por causa de um "u" maiúsculo! Obrigada pela ajuda!